# openssl API to perform the functionality of c_rehash

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, x509

I need to assign symbolic links to CA certificate files in a directory such that the symbolic link names should be hash values. This is required for the openssl API `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` to work.

This can be easily done using the command `openssl rehash` or `c_rehash`. But I need do it from my C program. Is there any openssl API or other alternatives for doing this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095440/hash-algorithm-for-certificate-crl-directory for a similar discussion, pointing out caveats (_e.g._ OpenSSL `c_rehash` changes in the past), etc.

Comment: @TJSaunders Thanks for your suggestion.